# Localizing of C# Win Forms

Tags: c#, localization

I am developing a WinForm application which require localization.
If I try to set the Localizable property of the form to True and set the text for all the languages then every thing works fine.

What I want is to maintain all languages resource files in a separate folder (one file for each form).

```
-Project
   -Resources
      -Language
          frmFirstForm.en-US.resx
          frmFirstForm.en-GB.resx
          frmSecondForm.en-US.resx
          frmSecondForm.en-GB.resx
   frmFirst.cs
   frmSecond.cs
```

In my resource file I have defined all strings as follows:

```
**Key              Value**
lblName          Name
lblAddress       Address
.....
```

The key is my control names, I will also keep form specific strings in the resource files. Now the issue is when I compile the solution, it do generate the language files but while running the application it just displays the default values. I don't even know whether the localized resource file is loaded or not. Also, though I have specified two separate form files but while compiling the system is generating only one single resource file per language for a project (means no separate resource file for FirstForm and SecondForm).

Is there any way where the form controls are changed as per the specified localized thread?

I have already added the following line in my main application Program.cs file:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Please suggest me how to proceed with this..

Comment: Unless you write words like "colour", you are not going to see an enormous difference between en-GB and en-US.  If you want to test it then just use a bogus word in en-GB.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am already using different strings for both the resource files..my apologies for not describing this at first stage..

Comment: You are using non-standard locations for the .resx files, always unwise to try to trip up the build system like that.  Check that the satellite assemblies are being generated.

Comment: Yes Satellite Assemblies are being generated in the respective folder en-US and en-GB under debug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ashish : [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59193/Localizing-a-Windows-Application-with-Satellite-As) is what you want exactly!!!!

Comment: That means that I need to traverse through all my form controls and set the localized resource one by one.....Not sure how will it impact the performance for my window having approximately 40 to 50 labels and other static controls..